# Pythagoras theorem error in C++

Tags: c++

My code to find out if the triangle is right angled and display "right" if not then"wrong" but it only works in one format (smaller sides->hypotenuse i.e Inputing 6 8 10 gives "right",which is true but Inputing 8 6 10 or 10 6 8 gives errors any other arrangement of the 3 values give an error though I set my if statements to work for any order.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, b, c, hypotenuse;

    while(cin >> a >> b >> c)
    {
        if(a > b && a > c)
        {
            hypotenuse = a;

            if(b * b + c * c == hypotenuse)
                cout << "right" << endl;
            else
                cout << "wrong" << endl;
        }
        else if(b > a && b > c)
        {
            hypotenuse = b;
            hypotenuse *= hypotenuse;

            if(a * a + c * c == hypotenuse)
                cout << "right" << endl;
            else
                cout << "wrong" << endl;
        }
        else
            hypotenuse = c;

        hypotenuse *= hypotenuse;

        if(a * a + b * b == hypotenuse)
            cout << "right" << endl;
        else
            cout << "wrong" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please state a clear question.

Comment: Formatted the code, so you can read it for the first time. Perhaps you'll notice missing `{}` block after `else` or that you didn't square `hypotenuse` in the case it's `a`.

Comment: And suddenly anyone sees the missing curly braces around the last else-block :)

Comment: You need to go back and speak to Pythagoras again.

Comment: I don't think "wrong" is the opposite of "right" when we are talking about a "right" triangle…

Answer (score 5):

I hope that after @LogicStuff formatted you code you can see that you don't square the hypotenuse if it is `a` and that you've missed braces around the last `else`.

However, another thing you should note is the amount of code duplication you have. Within every branch of your conditional you have the same code for printing whether this triangle is right. You could save this into a boolean variable and move the printing logic at the end of the loop.

Taking this one step further, does your problem require you to know which side of a triangle is a hypotenuse? From what you wrote it does not, and in that case you are doing extra work. Instead, you could simplify your code to:

```
int a, b, c;
while (cin >> a >> b >> c)
{
    bool right =  (b*b + c*c == a*a)
               || (a*a + c*c == b*b)
               || (a*a + b*b == c*c);

    if (right)
        cout << "right\n";
    else
        cout << "wrong\n";
}
```